# How to switch views by different button in one view controller using xcode storyboard or swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, user-interface

I am learning to use the Xcode v11 storyboard with swift for making an ios app recently.

I want to achieve something that looks like the picture I provide below.

There is only one view controller but inside there are three buttons.

By clicking different buttons, it will update the view with different table views? (I assume I should use table view)

Is there any way I can make it in the storyboard? Or I need to programmatically code it?
(For example, I feel easy to connect different view controller by ctrl+drag two view controller and let segue do the works)

I am self-learning so any advice, guide, short example or tutorial will be really helpful. Thanks!

For example, like I am not sure what tool should I use to achieve that many lines of text + number.
I feel like I should use the table view.

[my simple wireframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rd5Pt.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! You may start with learning how `UITableView` works. There are tons of resources out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you want to change the data and color of views on click of button .. for doing this

I'm attaching photos of code and output please check [image: for green part]
[for blue part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0kec.png)

[image: for red part]

Comment: Really appreciate! I will test it

Comment: sure .. will wait for your reply

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 ways of doing it.

1. Make 3 different ViewControllers that each hold a table view and a UIView with your buttons. When you click the specific button you trigger a seque to one of the 2 other ViewControllers. (All the tableviews can share the same custom UITableViewCell class).
2. The more simple solution. - You make 1 ViewController that holds a table view and your 3 buttons. - When you click "Red" you provide the tableviews datasource with "Red data" and then reload the TableView using tableView.reloadData(). and so forth for all the buttons.

So you basically change what you want to show in the TableView and then reloads it with that data.

But as Glenn suggests, read more about how UITableView works, and you will quickly discover how you can do it with solution 2 as I explained.

Good luck! And welcome to Stackoverflow.